# .htaccess - doesn't work subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^(/\.)]+)/([^(/\.)]+)/([^(/\.)]+)/([^(/\.)]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&id2=$2&id3=$3&id4=$4 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^([^(/\.)]+)/([^(/\.)]+)/([^(/\.)]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&id2=$2&id3=$3 [QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^([^(/\.)]+)/([^(/\.)]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&id2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^(/\.)]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

on my web presentation works well, but when I want to go to admin section and type just **/admin**, so I am redirected to **admin/?id=admin** (bad page) - for the displaying log-in form, I have to type **/admin/index.php** instead of simple **admin**.

Could you help me, how to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: is /admin/ a real directory? in that case you'll have to add another .htaccess in that directory that does the redirecting

Comment: but wouldn't be easier and cleaner as well to put into the frontend .htaccess?

Comment: `DirectorySlash Off` should fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved that by this way:

```
RewriteRule ^(admin)/(.*)$ $1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: You didn't say you wanted it to work like that, phrase your questions better!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of lots of rewrite rules you should have one rule that pushes everything through index.php, then use PHP to manage those pages instead using the `$_SERVER` variables.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

That's just my advice, however in answer to your original question try this as your first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/admin$ index.php?id=admin [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I am trying something like **RewriteRule ^/admin$ admin/login.php [QSA,L]
**, but unfortunately doesn't works